# Highest resolution for Google / Bing map API

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I am using Google static map with scale value 2: [example](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=28.2912661,-82.6213497&zoom=5&scale=2&size=395x305&maptype=satellite).

I want better resolution for both Google and bing map. I did not find anything useful for bing map regarding this. But for Google Map I found [this documentation page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#scale_values), which is very useful and I tried `scale:4` to get better resolution but as written on site I was unable to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Google Maps**

In free API you can't use scale 4. You can have 1280x1280 as the highest resolution like [this](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=28.6139,77.2090&zoom=10&scale=2&size=640x640&maptype=satellite).

You should use Google Maps API for work to do this.

**Bing Maps**

In Bing you can have 900px x 834px image, but I tried, and get the result that, It will work with 1440px x 937px(either can be height or width). You can try it too.
[937x1440 Image](http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Aerial/28.6139,77.2090/10?mapSize=937,1440&key=your_BING_key) and 1440x937 is acceptable too. Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Scale 4 is not available for Free API. You need to use Google Maps API for Work.

[Images sizes allowed](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Imagesizes)

Comment: Thanks but can you help me to get highest resolution in bing too.

Comment: you can try following properties to get desired results in static bing maps. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh667439.aspx

Comment: For Bing, the limits are 900px x 834px (width x height) according to the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx